# where do i save the .txt file in the Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a model "Geo" in my rails application like below.
where do i save the text.txt file in the Rails application and what address do I call in the particular line of code File.open("`/india/text.txt`")

Note: The text.txt is data containing txt file.

```
 class Geo < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :country_iso2, :country_name, :district, :latitude, :locality, :longitude, :state_iso2, :state_name, :street, :taluka, :zip

    def self.create_or_save(locality_s, zip_s, state_s, district_s)
        g = Geo.where(zip: zip_s).first
        g = Geo.new(zip: zip_s) if g.blank?
        g.locality = locality_s
        g.state_name = state_s
        g.district = district_s
        g.save
    end

    def self.mine
        File.open("/india/text.txt") do |f|
            f.each_line do |line|
                li = line.split(":")
                    locality = li[0].to_s.strip
                    zip = li[1].to_s.strip
                    state = li[2].to_s.strip
                    district = li[3].to_s.strip
                Geo.create_or_save(locality, zip, state, district)
            end 
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: why not use your db for that?

Comment: Actually , i use to fetch date from txt file and save it to DB.

Comment: You can keep the data files in public/data/ ..... but if say /india/file.txt it will search directory 'india' in the root directory of the host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use `Rails.root` :

```
Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'txt', 'india', 'text.txt')
```

which maps to /app/assets/txt/india/text.txt